# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'camera' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' on line 205

Tags: javascript, php, css

That Doesn't work .  **Check Out ThIS !! i Have exactly same Problem .
.            [how to add Wordpress phpshortcode into HTML page or custom template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535291/how-to-add-wordpress-phpshortcode-into-html-page-or-custom-template)**

for sure it's php error .i wanna ad this Shortcode [`<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite] '); ?>` ] to my custom html template , so for this, i have to change my html based template to a php based  and while changin html to php !!

i got this error !!

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'camera' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' on line 205

and 2nd line in below code is line 205

```
<ul id="nav">






<li><a href="javascript:goTo('camera');"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Home</strong></span></p></a></li>

     <li><a href="javascript:goTo('Movies');"><i class="fa fa-film" ></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Movies</strong></span></p></a></li>



     <li><a href="javascript:goTo('TVshow');"><i class="fa fa-television"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>TV.Show</strong></span></p></a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:goTo('Filter');"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Filter</strong></span></p></a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:goTo('Contact');"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Contact</strong></span></p></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: That looks like a PHP error message...

Comment: As for those who downvoted this, it would be useful to give feedback so the OP can learn why it was voted down and how to improve his question.

Answer (score 0):

This error it's from php please post ful code so I can fix it for you , you probally forgot a string contatenation or a

> ;

or

> }

in the end of your file or function

It can also be a javascript problem change your code to this and let's see how it works

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="javascript:goTo('camera')"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Home</strong></span></p></a></li>

 <li><a href="javascript:goTo('Movies')"><i class="fa fa-film" ></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Movies</strong></span></p></a></li>



 <li><a href="javascript:goTo('TVshow')"><i class="fa fa-television"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>TV.Show</strong></span></p></a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:goTo('Filter')"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Filter</strong></span></p></a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:goTo('Contact')"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Contact</strong></span></p></a></li>
</ul>
```

change your php to this

```
<?php require( '../wp-load.php' ); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>  
    <ul id="nav"> <li><a href="javascript:goTo('camera');">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Home</strong></span></p></a></li> </ul> 
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

and change your shortcode to with no blank sapaces

It's right this way `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?>`

Comment: <?php
require( '../wp-load.php' );

echo '


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 
<head>  </head>
<body> 
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="javascript:goTo('camera');"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>Home</strong></span></p></a></li>
</ul>
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]</body>
</html>
'); ?>

Comment: see my changes if it does solve your problem please mark answer as right

Comment: no bro !! That Doesn't work . But Thanks  ya response at  least Check Out The Link Below !! i Have exactly same Problem ..            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535291/how-to-add-wordpress-phpshortcode-into-html-page-or-custom-template

Comment: Could you send all the files for me to see it whats is wrong?

Comment: Hey I please change your short code to <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?> so no blank spaces

Comment: your code working but  not rendering the search bar properly . **Check this [Link](http://movieeater.com/wp-content/420.php) ,This what happen after inserting ur code**.  And **check this [Link](http://movieeater.com) _u can see red color search bar on this link_ thats how i want the search bar on 1st Link**.  Hope u understand. And if u need file or if ya help on teamviewer contact me *madyvwake@gmail.com*

Comment: It  looks to be a problem with your css send both files to download I will check